# firebase storage images must i have image extension?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I've been using firebase to store my images for quite awhile, then realized one day my downloadURL does not have the image extension, and realized from the documentation that it should have already been added as such when retrieving the child from storageRef.

```
storageRef.child('images/stars.jpg').getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
  // `url` is the download URL for 'images/stars.jpg'
```

I have always done something like below which is essentially omitting the `.jpg` or `.png` extension to the image, and it has been functioning well/same for me since the image still loads on my web browser (using the downloadURL).

```
let storageName = `CatsAreCool_${dateTime.seconds}`;
storage.ref(`test_images/cats/` + storageName)
.put().then().getDownloadURL()...
```

I am wondering if there are any downsides of this (will it affect anything, website speed etc), and should i change to add the image extension in manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the file is irrelevant to Cloud Storage when it comes to behavior and performance.  It is just a string.  You can give that string any meaning you want, but Cloud Storage treats it the same in all cases.  There are no advantages or disadvantages to choosing various strings - just go with whatever you find most helpful for your app.